# PYC files compiled with py_compile.compile deleted by Aptana Studio (Windows)

Tags: python, compilation, python-3.x, aptana, pydev

When I compile on Windows a py-file into another folder then the pyc-file shortly appears and disappears an instant later.

Here the sample code I execute:

```
from py_compile import compile
source = r"E:\proj\abc\__init__.py"
dest = r"E:\proj\bin_abc\__init__.pyc"
print(compile(source, cfile=dest, doraise=True))
```

Now, if I compile the pyc in the same destination folder than the py-file resides in, then it does **not** disappear ?!??

Has anybody an explanation for this behavior?

**Update**: I figured out that it is **Aptana Studio that is responsible for deleting the pyc-files**:

- the files **remain** if I compile them into a **directory outside** my Aptana project. (If `dest` is `E:\temp\__init__.pyc` for example).
- the files are **deleted** if I run the code snipped outside Aptana and **Aptana is open**.
- the files **remain** if I run the code snipped and **Aptana is closed**

Why does Aptana delete my pyc-files?

Comment: Works for me. Python 3.2.2 on Linux. Looking at the source of `compile()`, there is nothing that can remove the file. I suspect the disappearance of your file is unrelated to Python.

Comment: @LennartRegebro you were right ... see my update

Comment: It probably deletes them because it doesn't want stale pyc files lying around.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I googled a bit and found the answer myself...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Automatic pyc deletion is a "feature" of [PyDev](http://pydev.org/history_pydev.html#release-2-2-2):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One small comment on the sample code provided with regards to the desired compilation and changes occurring **from python version 3.2**, the destination file extension is specified with ".pyc" but the compile option is not specified and is by default set to -1, meaning that the invoked command is going to perform an optimized compiling of the file. The extension chosen in the dest variable in this case should be ".pyo" instead of ".pyc".

To generate a ".pyc" extension compiled file, add argument optimized=0.